# AngularJS and dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've a HTML line with AngularJS directive that I am inserting dynamically through some jQuery controls that are being used since 2009. I cannot change this Control. However, I want to start using angular JS.

The generated HTML for a grid, column rating, is:

```
  <div star-rating rating-value="1005" max="5"> </div>
```

What I want is to get this html compiled.

At present AngularJS is not able to see this dynamically generated HTML.

The only way I can think of is if I call a javascript function for each jQuery insert (The Grid control I am using can compile JavaScript function).

```
fnCompileDynamicHTML('<div star-rating rating-value=23 max=5></div>)
```

And function:

```
fnCompileDynamicHTML(html) {
    return $compile(html)($scope) // or something?
}
```

I have followed what is mentioned [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CcRrN/). However my application is complaining about:

```
App Already Bootstrapped with this Element.
```

Well it is not because it is a new object, and new inner HTML.

This is what I have in the loop of 100:

```
 evt.row.cells[glbCandidateListColumnIndex.rank].innerHTML = '<div star-rating rating-value="' + rank + '" ></div>';
 fnCompileDynamicAngularJS(evt.row.cells[glbCandidateListColumnIndex.rank]);
```

Please help.

Comment: `evt.row.cells[glbCandidateListColumnIndix.rank].appendChild(fnCompileDynamicAngularJS('<div star-rating rating-value="' + rank + '" ></div>'));` ? A call to `$compile(html)(scope)` returns an `$element` which you have to `append` to the right place. You may also need a call to `.node()` on the returned `$element` to get the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You should either load Angular.js after the DOM compilation by your foreign library is done, calling `angular.bootstrap` [(documented here)](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/angular.bootstrap), or you can force the compilation of that particular DOM node manually (harder!!!)

As an example:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('myDirective', function () {});
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
```

That should work already!